# Post comment onto a webpage, using facebook graph api

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

A small question about facebook graph api.
I have been using the official [Facebook Graph API PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk).

I also included the facebook social comments plugin widget on my web page.
Is it possible to post a comment on to the web page, using Graph api of facebook ?

The user will be logged into my web application using facebook, and then he must be able to post facebook comment on the web page in my application, through API. So the widget will be displaying all the comments that are posted directly on the page, and those that are posted through API.

So far, i have tried this AJAX code:

```
<?php 
$token = $facebook->getAccessToken(); 
?>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" 
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.post('https://graph.facebook.com/comments/?ids=http://mywebsite.com/comments.php?id=123',{ name: 'John', message: 'Testing comments', 'method': 'POST', 'format': 'json', 'access_token': '<?php echo $token; ?>'},
function(data) {           
});
</script>
```

But this is returning an OAUTH Exception:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An unknown error has occurred.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 1
   }
}
```

I am requesting enough permissions while setting up the login url:

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
               'scope' => 'email,publish_stream,publish_actions,read_stream,user_about_me,user_events,create_event'
            ));
```

**Note:**
I am including the facebook widget on my page, using the following code:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.mywebsite.com/comments.php?
id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>" data-width="370" data-num-posts="5"></div>
```

**Script:**

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


  <div id='fb-root'></div>
    <script src='http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'></script>
    <!--<p><a onclick='postToFeed(); return false;'>Post to Feed</a></p>-->
    <p id='msg'></p>

    <script> 
      FB.init({appId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", status: true, cookie: true});

      function postToFeed() {

        // calling the API ...
        var obj = {
          method: 'feed',
          redirect_uri: 'http://www.mywebsite.com/comments.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>',
          link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
          picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
          name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
          caption: 'Reference Documentation',
          description: 'Using Dialogs to interact with users.'
        };

        function callback(response) {
          document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
        }
        FB.ui(obj, callback);
      }    
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not the correct syntax for posting comments. At least the postId is missing:
Here how you call it via API (php sdk)

```
$facebook ->api('/'.$post_id.'/comments', 
 'post', 
   array(
      'message' => 'users comment',
   )
);
```

You cannot use the JQuery $.post for generating APi Calls. Use JQuery to call a PHP script with the API call inside.

Comment: I am not sure what to be used for the post_id. Is it the url of my webpage, that has the facebook comments widget?

Comment: postId = the Id of the post where the comments belongs to. Without the API does not know where to put to comment to. Is the widget from Facebook? Is it iFrame based or Javascript? Did you write it on your own?

Comment: The widget is not from facebook. I have manually included the widget on my page, using an iframe code.

Comment: How do you get the comments? Loaded via API? Can you provide some code here? I mean to show up comments you also need postIds? Without more information about the widget and the code inside it is hard to help.

Comment: Edited my question with all the code, that loads facebook comments in my page.

Comment: Do you try to post comments on you website via Facebook? Or do you try to to post comments on Facebook? What is the content of your http://www.mywebsite.com/comments.php

Comment: I am trying to post comments on my web site page, through an API call from another page. The content on my web page is a dynamic content from database, based on the id parameter passed in the url.

Comment: That will not work. The facebook api is meant to use for interacting with facebook content. You can only comment Facebook posts via the API. Your post suggest that you are displaying comments from facebook on your page and you want to comment them. You cannot use it as library for page to page communication.

Comment: Ok, i am actually not displaying comments from facebook post on my page. I have just setup a comments widget on my pages by specifying a unique url for each page. But i understand now that it is not possible to add comments via API on to my web page. Thanks for your suggestion.